# Scatter plot with variable marker size (seaborn)

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, data-visualization, seaborn

I am using a seaborn `pairplot` to plot a scatter plot of different dimensions of my datapoints. However, I want the markers of the datapoints to have a size that corresponds to one of the dimensions of the datapoints. I have the following code:

```
markersize = 1000* my_dataframe['dim_size'] / sum(my_dataframe['dim_size'])

sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.5, rc={'figure.figsize': [11, 8]})
sns.set_style("darkgrid", {"axes.facecolor": ".9"})

kws = dict(s=markersize, linewidth=.5, edgecolor="w")

sbax = sns.pairplot(my_dataframe, hue='dim_hue' x_vars=['dim_1', 'dim_2'], y_vars=['dim_3', 'dim_4'], size=5, plot_kws=kws)

axes = sbax.axes
for a in axes.flatten():
    a.set_ylim([0,1])
    a.set_xlim([0,1])
```

If I do `print(kws)`, I see in the dictionary that the sizes are all different and vary from 40 to 2000. However, the markers on the plot are all the same. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Btw, this works very well with `lmplot` if I set the parameter `scatter_kws={"s": markersize}`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

size = 100 * (iris.petal_length / iris.petal_length.max())
g = sns.PairGrid(iris, vars=["sepal_length", "sepal_width"], size=5)
g.map(plt.scatter, s=size)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves just half of my problem, as it doesn't work if I set `hue='species'` into the `PairGrid` initialization. How can I manage to have hue and different markersize at the same time?

Comment: Actually, if I look closer, there is a difference in the marker sizes, but the difference is very minor, almost unnoticeable. Why is this happening?

Comment: You should see a better size difference using `size = 100 * (iris.petal_length - iris.petal_length.min()) / (iris.petal_length.max() - iris.petal_length.min()))`.